# Inserting a String (text link markup) to an HTML page via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, appendchild, createelement

I have a variable `topBarText`.
That variable is a String that contains a text link `"<a href="index.html">Link</a>"`
I want to insert that string onto the page via Javascript (I am limited to JUST Javascript)
The variable is declared as `topBarText`
and executing `document.body.appendChild(topBarText);` gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

What do I need to do to append this variable to the page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Node like that string.

```js
const a = document.createElement('a'); // is a node
a.href = 'index.html';
a.innerHTML = 'Link';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```